# Why doesn't my relative layout take whole screen height

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout

So, i have simple layout with some text and a button. Text is positioned at start and takes, on some phones, more height then the height of screen so i have it positioned in scroll view. Next to that text i have one more textview and a button which should be positioned in the bottom right of the screen. The problem is that one large screens my button isn't at bottom but there where the text ends, and i can see that my relativelayout doesn't take whole height of the scrollView. My layout:

```
<ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Some dummy text"
        android:textColor="#969696"
        android:textSize="13dp" />




    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
        android:text="some dummy text2"
        android:textColor="#969696"
        android:textSize="13dp" />



    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/btn49_2x" />

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

My real layout is a bit more complex so i need to use relative layout. But how to make sure it takes whole screen height?

I tried setting height to `wrap:content` but no effect.

Comment: Why not just set layout_height = "fill_parent" ?

Comment: check @idaNakav answer it will solve your issue.

Comment: Because of scroll view, remove scroll view or add android:fillViewport="true" in ScrollView

Comment: @ManmeetSinghBatra do you know why he is using ScrollView>

Comment: Can somebody explain why downvotes? It's real question, i didn't see any copy of it and i got real answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `android:fillViewport="true"` to your ScrollView